# Why does the y transform position of an object change with different types of collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

A simple tutorial example. There is an object that has 2 colliders - a box collider and a capsule collider.
All collider parameters - height, offset, etc. - are the same.
If the box collider is active, the player moves higher (changing y transform position). If the collider capsule is active, the player moves lower.

Why is this and how to make sure that the player does not move when changing colliders?
Video https://youtu.be/T_uwJETteHs

[image: Object]

[image: Result]

PS
Fitting by hand is not a scientific option.

I adjusted the collider manually - but this is a bad option.

Comment: well the height of the object isnt changing which was what your title says, what you're asking is why did the capsule mean it rested on the ground and the box didnt..  The height was the same in both although given one is rounded there is likely some room for float rounding differences

Comment: Physics are usually not 100% exact for performance reasons. Might be related to some of the [Physics2D Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) like e.g. `Default Contact Offset  Set a proximity distance value for Colliders to be considered in contact, even though they are not actually in contact. Colliders whose distance is less than the sum of their contactOffset values generate contacts. This allows the collision detection
system to predictively enforce the contact constraint even when the objects are slightly separated. ...`

Comment: @BugFinder  I have corrected the title of the question. My question is why does the object move when colliders are equal? This is a problem when I use 2 switchable colliders on the player.